# Symbolizing "somebody likes everybody bob likes"

Tags: logic, education, quantifiers

I would like to know how to symbolize "somebody likes everybody bob likes"

I have tried the following:
for all of x (if bob likes x, then for some y, y likes x)

which I think would look like:
$∀x∃y(Lbx\Rightarrow (Lyx))$

Is this correct?

Thank you

Comment: What you have quantified is the statement, "For all individuals $x,$ if Bob likes $x,$ then there is someone who likes $x.$" But this is not the same as, "There exists an individual who likes every individual that Bob likes."

Comment: Your sentence is "Everybody Bob likes is liked by someone." This is different from "Someone likes everybody Bob likes". The point is that in the first sentence, the "somebody" could be different for different people liked by Bob. For example, if Bob likes Mary and Sue then your sentence allows for the "someone" whole likes Mary to be different from the "someone" who likes Sue. On the other hand, the second sentence (the one you want) is talking about a single person who likes *everybody* Bob likes.

Answer (score 2):

Observe that the phrase, "Somebody likes everybody that Bob likes" is equivalent to the phrase, "There exists an individual (Alice) such that for every individual $I,$ if Bob likes $I,$ then Alice likes $I,$ as well."

Quantifying that gives us $(\exists A \,|\, \forall I, B \text{ likes } I \implies A \text{ likes } I).$

Comment: okay thanks so much

Answer (score 1):

You've symbolized the statement as a *universal*, but the statement is actually an *existential* statement. It asserts (first and foremost) that there exists an individual. It's more clear if you write it more formally: There exists an individual, $x$, such that $x$ likes every individual Bob likes. Thus, we have

$$\exists x (\forall y (Lby \to Lxy))$$

Answer (score 0):

Your formalization reads "Everyone who Bob likes is liked by someone"; but that permits for the possibility that each of Bob's liked ones is liked by someone different:

```
        />  Henry <- Mary
    Bob ->  Tom   <- John     ("->" = "likes")
        \>  Susan <- Josy
```

whereas the the original sentence asserts that there should be at least one single person who likes all of them. You therefore have to swap the existential and the universal quantifier:

$$\exists y \forall x(Lbx \to Lyx)$$

This only permits structures like the following:

```
        />  Henry <\ 
    Bob ->  Tom   <- John     ("->" = "likes")
        \>  Susan </
```

-- as desired.